# Does the "tea" break in cricket always include actual tea?

Tags: cricket, etiquette

Tomorrow is my first match against St. Peters junior team and my coach told me that it will involve a tea break. I do not wish to drink tea - will this be expected or enforced during the tea break?

Comment: If you are playing cricket in a place like India drinking tea or any real hot beverage will have the real chance of making you faint. Tea is also a diuretic which will make it really potent at dehydrating you.

Answer (score 5):

In cricket, "tea" refers to a break between either playing sessions or innings; it is also the name of the supplied food and drink selection at that break.

While there would generally be tea (the beverage) available to drink at tea (the break) it's not typically the *only* drink available, nor is drinking it compulsory.

Answer (score -2):

@motosubatsu's answer is very true answer, under normal circumstances. Most games I believe that to be true.

However, upon rereading your question again, I thought of the possibility that your  coach (since it appears he stressed the tea break to you, a new player) may indeed 'enforce' actual tea at the break, as a *learning experience*.

Don't worry overly, it's not THAT bad, at least if there is sugar and some sort of cream available. Oh, and good luck with the match!

Comment: There's no indication that a TEA break was stressed, just a tea break. There are reasons to avoid drinking tea that have nothing to do with its flavor (which, IMO, is ruined by adding tea or cream).